# Using PrintStream in PrintWriter formatting error

Tags: java, printwriter, printstream

I'm fiddling with a basic code that utilizes methods to create values, and I want it to write into a text file and format the values, however the \n in my printf statements will not actually indent the solution.

```
File surfaceG = new File("SurfaceGravity.txt");
surfaceG.createNewFile();
PrintWriter write = new PrintWriter(surfaceG);
String placer = "";
write.printf("%5sPlanetary Data\n", placer);
write.printf("%10sPlanet, placer);
write.close();
```

The solution I'm aiming for is

```
     Planetary Data
         Planet
```

However the solution this code will give is

`Planetary Data          Planet`

Why won't the \n in my printf statements compute through to the textfile?

Comment: Its working fine.one small mistake is missing quote. write.printf("%10sPlanet, placer);

Comment: You're using Windows, aren't you? The `"\n"` character is only a newline on Linux-like platforms. Use "%n" in a System.out.printf instead of `"\n"` in order to be platform-independent.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou  Very helpful, honestly wracking my brain